# DIRTY JSON Creation there must be a better way

Tags: c#, .net, json

This works but is a mess. I must be doing something wrong.

```
    DSDSUser user =     userFactory.GetUserByUsername(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            var messages = user.SystemUser.MessageStages;


            var ret = "[" + messages.Aggregate("", (current, message) => current + (@"[""" + message.Id.ToString() + @""",""" + message.Name + @"""]" + ",")).TrimEnd(',') + "]";

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.Write(ret);

>>>>>>>> 
[
  ["111","Call to members"],
  ["112","Real Estate"],
  ["113","Call to sale"],
  ["131","Snowy Day"],
  ["123","No school today"],
  ["101","Last payment"],
  ["145","Turn off notice"],
  ["113","Bill Collection"],
  ["167","Message default"],
  ["233","Message default"],
  ["323","Message default"],
  ["233","VM message"]  
]
```

> > > There must be a cleaner way to make this Json

Comment: There is a great NuGet package for serializing JSON objects.  The Newtonsoft.JSON package should work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: There is some chance that similar questions where asked before - have you tried to find similar one? The answer is also depends on framework (as some like ASP.Net MVC have built in ways to deal with JSON...)

Comment: I have that NuGet installed and could not find the property to set get the desired  output. Yes, I looked for 20 minutes before I posted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Json.Net via the package manager console in Visual Studio:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 6.0.8
```

Then serialize your object with:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messages);
```

You can add `[JsonIgnore]` to any fields on the `MessageStages` object you don't want to get serialized.